# Set cookies and do auto login

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I am developing google chrome extension where I receives all the cookies of particular website e.g. `www.example.com` and I set it in the current instance of chrome browser through chrome extension JavaScript. Basically I need to pretend auto login using cookies I receive from third party. I am setting cookies using below code:

```
chrome.cookies.set({ url: url, name: "cookiename", value : "cookievalue", domain : "domain", path : "path" });
```

It did login sometimes and it did not sometimes. I might need to do other than setting cookies e.g. clear localstorage, clear cache, clear cache storage etc.. for which I am not sure. I am not able to figure it out why it is not working sometimes.

Also, if you could shed some lights on auto-login or whether it is possible this way or not?

Comment: I would try setting the cookie via [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie).

Comment: @wOxxOm, is not `document.cookie` and `chrome.cookies.set` are different? `document` refers to the current open tab, correct?

Comment: @wOxxOm Why is that?

Comment: Because `document.cookie` is synchronous and thus the cookie will be set  before you submit the login (in case you do it in a content script). On the other hand it may be easier to log in in the `chrome.cookies.set` callback (you're not doing it currently judging by the code).

Comment: @wOxxOm, Should I click login inside callback function of `chrome.cookies.set`? I am setting `chrome.cookies.set` in background.js so should I go for `document.cookie` or `chrome.cookies.set`?

Comment: I assume you inject a content script or send a message to an already injected one. Start with the easiest of course: the callback.

Comment: Now, wOxxOm's comment makes more sense. Can you show what you do after setting the cookie?

Answer (score 1):

This is <del>probably</del> quite possibly not a client-side issue.

Unless you're 100% sure how session management works for that particular site, the cookie you're setting might simply not be accepted as valid when implanted like that.

Comment: I receive cookies from third party and they uses selenium to login and then extract all cookies. They will return the extracted cookies to me and then I inject all cookies to chrome browser using chrome extension JavaScript. Do not you think this should work as it is valid cookies? In fact it worked sometimes and it did not sometimes so I think session management is not causing the issue.

Comment: There may be other factors validating the session than just one cookie by the server, maybe some browser fingerprinting. After all, you want some security against exactly this attack.

Comment: I do not need security as this is not attack. Cookies sender is controlled by me and I receive it in chrome extension.